# Count rows of dataframes within a list of dataframes

Tags: r, sapply, purrr

I have a list of dataframes, `str(datalist,max.level = 1)` reveals

```
List of 9
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   200 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ :'data.frame':   41 obs. of  21 variables:
```

Now some the variables within the 21 variables of the dataframe are again dataframes. For eg. the 18th variable is a dataframe called `topics` which in turn contains 3 variables. How do I get the count of rows in each of the `topics` dataframe?

I tried using the `map()` function from the `purrr` package : `x <- map(datalist, ~.x[["topics"]])` and thereafter `sapply(x, NROW)` but this gives me the number of rows of the original dataframe and not the `topics` dataframe. Any help would be appreciated.

To give you an example of what the `topics` dataframe looks like, `datalist[[1]]$topics[[1]]`

```
                  urlkey                   name    id
1            selfdefense           Self-Defense   443
2                martial           Martial Arts   681
3                jujitsu              Jiu Jitsu  9615
4     mixed-martial-arts     Mixed Martial Arts 15514
5             kickboxing             Kickboxing 18225
6              jiu-jitsu              Jiu-jitsu 21219
7     brazilian-jiujitsu    Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu 22237
8 mma-mixed-martial-arts MMA Mixed Martial Arts 35023
9    brazilian-jiu-jitsu    Brazilian Jiu Jitsu 46818
```

Comment: Gives me `NULL` for the original 9 dataframes

Comment: You need to supply a reproducible example of your data. For instance, you can have a data.frame in a list column of another data.frame but that means the whole data.frame would be in a single "cell" or row of that column. Do you have 1 data.frame in each cell/row of that column? Try `mtcars$topics <- list(iris); str(mtcars)`

Comment: @docendo thanks for pointing out the reproducible example bit. Will definitely bear in mind for future queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you described works for me:

Make a reproducible example:

```
datalist <- list(
  data.frame(V1 = 1:2, topics = I(list(mtcars, mtcars))),
  data.frame(V1 = 1:2, topics = I(list(mtcars, mtcars)))
)
str(datalist)
# List of 2
#  $ :'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
# ..$ V1    : int [1:2] 1 2
# ..$ topics:List of 2
# .. ..$ :'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
# .. .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# .. .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# .. .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
# .. .. ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# .. .. ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# .. .. ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# .. .. ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# .. .. ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# .. .. ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# .. .. ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# .. .. ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# .. ..$ :'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
# .. .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# .. .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# .. .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
# .. .. ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# .. .. ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# .. .. ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# .. .. ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# .. .. ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# .. .. ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# .. .. ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# .. .. ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
# $ :'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
# ..$ V1    : int [1:2] 1 2
# ..$ topics:List of 2
# .. ..$ :'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
# .. .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# .. .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# .. .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
# .. .. ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# .. .. ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# .. .. ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# .. .. ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# .. .. ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# .. .. ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# .. .. ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# .. .. ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# .. ..$ :'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
# .. .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
# .. .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# .. .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
# .. .. ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
# .. .. ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
# .. .. ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# .. .. ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# .. .. ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
# .. .. ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# .. .. ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
# .. .. ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Your solution:

```
library(purrr)
map(datalist, ~ sapply(.x[["topics"]], NROW))
# [[1]]
# [1] 32 32
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 32 32
```

Comment: Shifting the `sapply` within the `map` function works. @Aurele thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
count_rows <- function(dfs) {
nrow(dfs$topics)
}
count <- lapply(datalist, count_rows)
```

The `count_rows` function just subsets each dataframe in the list and then applies `nrow` on your "topics" dataframe.

Comment: Add some comments and description.

Comment: @troh I am afraid this returns a list of 9 NULLs

Comment: @Dhiraj can you show what the topics dataframe looks like?